# Scale/Resize the ScatterViewItem which is create through DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, pixelsense

I got a problem with scaling the scatterViewItem which is created through DataTemplate.

I built something like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727736

It also have the same problem with my project(if you like to see:-) [mtscrumtool.codeplex.com](http://mtscrumtool.codeplex.com)), the scatterViewItem couldn't be scaled.

The Datatemplate of the ScatterViewItem shows below:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ScatterViewItemDataTemplate" >
<Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="White" Margin="10">
    <StackPanel Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static s:SurfaceColors.Accent3BrushKey}}">
        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="20"/>

        <Label Content="{Binding CanDrag}"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="18"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: What other properties/style are you setting on the scatterviewitem?  DataTemplate is unlikely to be the source of your problem

Answer (score 0):

Check the `ItemContainerStyle` property of the ScatterView and see if it sets `CanScale="False"`, if not then try and set the property of the `ItemContainerStyle` by setting a setter of `CanScale="true"` property.